# How to show a handle on SWT's SashForm?

Tags: java, swt

How can I show a handle/visual indication on a SWT's `SashForm`?

With my code, there is no feedback to the user, that there is infact a sash form:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm;

// ...

SashForm leftRightSashForm = new SashForm(panel, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.SMOOTH);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there's currently no way to alter SashForm divider appearence.

A partial solution could be to change the background color of Sash itself, which also changes the color of divider, like this:

```
sashForm.setBackground(sashForm.getDisplay().getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
```

[image]